# Structures and fprintf()

Tags: c, printf

I was wondering if it is possible to use fprintf() with a structure, because I know you can't use a "%" for the structure.

```
struct blackhole_register
{
int userID;
float blackhole_Mass;
char blackhole_ID[5];
char name_First[11];
char name_Last[16];
};
int main ()
{
struct blackhole_register input;
struct blackhole_register output;

FILE *blackhole_file;

if ((blackhole_file = fopen("Holter.txt","w")) == NULL)
{
    printf("File location not found, the program will now end\n");
}
else
    printf("Schwarzschild Radius Application by Jonathan Holter\n\n");

    printf("\nFirst Name: ");
    fgets(input.name_First,11,stdin);

    printf("\nLast Name: ");
    fgets(input.name_Last,16,stdin);

    printf("\nUser ID: ");
    fgets(input.userID,4,stdin);

    printf("\nBlack Hole Name/ID: ");
    fgets(input.blackhole_ID,20,stdin);

    printf("\nBlack Hole Mass (Solar Masses): ");
    fgets(input.blackhole_Mass,3,stdin);
```

This is what I have so far, any help would be wonderful!!

Comment: You can `fwrite` any binary blob you desire.

Comment: How would fprintf know anything about the structure?

Comment: Bugs: `fgets(input.userID,4,stdin);` with an `int` field.  ` fgets(input.blackhole_ID,20,stdin);` should be ` fgets(input.blackhole_ID,sizeof input.blackhole_ID,stdin);`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic `%serialize-my-struct` flag in `printf` format strings.  You'll need to `printf` each field in the struct separately.  Consider writing a function `int print_blackhole_register(FILE*, const blackhole_register*)`.

Comment: Some implementations though allow dynamic extension of the recognised format specifiers.

Comment: Agreed @Deduplicator.  And, occasionally coders may write specialized 'printf()'-like functions that extends the normal format string to include things like structures, date & time values, etc.